# Different Output With the Same Logical Input

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two tables **'test1'** and **'test2'** with the single column **'id'**.
**'test1'** table contains the 5 rows with values like 1,2,3,4,5 and **'test2'** table contains the 3 rows with values like 1,2,3 then if i want to get the just 4,5 from **'test1'**
I am using two below queries

```
select a.id 
  from test1 a,test2 b 
  where a.id=b.id(+) and b.id is null;
```

output:4,5

```
select a.id 
  from test1 a left outer join test2 b 
                on     a.id=b.id 
                   and b.id is null;
```

output:1,2,3,4,5

Both the queries are similar logically but these are giving different outputs...

Please explain me is there any difference....

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `(+)` is deprecated by Oracle. Don't use it any more

Comment: The `b.id is null` test has to be in the `WHERE` clause because it's an assertion about whether the join succeeded - so it can't be part of the `JOIN` conditions.

Comment: if you want 4,5 that is on the two tables, why not use a join ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you provide a link with this information about `(+)` sign please?

Comment: "these are giving different outputs" how are they different?  Is one of them correct?

Comment: In the context of your two queries, the difference is that the `(+)` join evaluates the `b.id is null` condition in the context of the filter expression, while ANSI join evaluates the same condition in the context of the join criterion.

Comment: @JorgeCampos See the accepted answer in the duplicate question. It quotes the manual

Comment: Change your second query to "where b.id is null" rather than "and b.id is null" to make both queries have the same intent, and hence the same answer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It is not deprecated at all. The docs recommends to not use it because of the restrictions that came along. I mean Deprecated as the meaning of the word. I'm just saying that because I have lots of oracle magazine (since 2001) and never saw such warning about deprecation. Thats why I asked for a link. I was very curious. :) but thanks anyway.